# Show CLOB data in IFS

Tags: plsql, ifstream, ifs, plsql-package

I created a CLOB column in Database and now I want to show the data via custom field (Read only). But custom field have the limit length
(4000)
Is there a way to solve this problem?

I tried to convert my result to XML and show it via custom field but it was not displayed.